# Why wont chr(27) work properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought

I'm going to start by providing my code, first.

```
import sys

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def print_box(pick):
    top_line=     '     '+u'\u2554'+u'\u2550'*80 + u'\u2557'
    bottom_line=  '     '+u'\u255A'+u'\u2550'*80 + u'\u255D'
    middle_line=  '     '+u'\u2560'+u'\u2550'*80 + u'\u2563'
    empty_line=   '     '+u'\u2551'+' '*80 + u'\u2551'

    print top_line 
    print content('#' + str(national_pokedex[pick])+'  ' + english_name[pick] )
    print middle_line
    print content('Evolves from ' + evolution[pick])
    print middle_line
    print_description_by_space (description[pick])
    print bottom_line
#----------------------------------------------------------------


def content(print_string):
    if len(print_string)% 2 == 0:
        space=''
    else:
        space=' '

    return ' '*5 + u'\u2551' + ' '* ((80-len(print_string))/2) + print_string +' '* ((80-len(print_string))/2) +space+ u'\u2551'
#----------------------------------------------------------------


def print_description(des_string):
    lines=int(len(des_string)/75) +1
    x=0
    print content('Description')
    print '     '+u'\u255F'+u'\u2500'*80 + u'\u2562'
    for i in range(0,lines):
       print content(des_string[x:x+75])
       x=x+75
#----------------------------------------------------------------


def print_description_by_space(description):
    word_list = description.split()
    word_list.append('END')
    word_list_lenght = len(word_list)-1
    place_in_list = 0
    count = 0

    while count < word_list_lenght:
        print_string = ' '
        while (len(print_string)+len(word_list[place_in_list])) <= 78 and place_in_list < word_list_lenght:
            print_string = print_string + word_list[place_in_list] + ' '
            place_in_list += 1

        print '     '+u'\u2551'+' '+print_string+' ' * (79-len(print_string))+u'\u2551'
        count = place_in_list
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#  Data
#----------------------------------------------------------------    

national_pokedex=[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
english_name=['Bulbasaur','Ivysaur','Venusaur','Charmander','Charmeleon','Charizard','Squirtle','Wartortle','Blastoise','Caterpie','Metapod','Butterfree','Weedle','Kakuna','Beedrill','Pidgey','Pidgeotto','Pidgeot','Rattata','Raticate','Spearow','Fearow','Ekans','Arbok','Pikachu']
evolution=['Egg','Bulbasaur','cIvysaur','Egg','Charmander','Charmeleon','Egg','Squirtle','Wartortle','Egg','Caterpie','Metapod','Egg','Weedle','Kakuna','Egg','Pidgey','Pidgeotto','Egg','Rattata','Egg','Spearow','Egg','Ekans','Pichu']
description=["Bulbasaur, known as Fushigidane in Japan,[1] is a Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. Designed by Ken Sugimori, their name is a combination of the words \"bulb\" and \"dinosaur.\" First appearing in Pokemon Red and Blue as a Starter Pokemon, they later appeared in subsequent sequels, spin-off games, related merchandise, and animated and printed adaptations of the franchise.",
        "Ivysaur , Fushigis, Fushigiso, known as the Seed Pokemon, represents the evolved form of Bulbasaur, one of the three starting Pokemon available to players in Pokemon Red and Blue and their various remakes; it evolves into the final form of Venusaur. Aside from becoming taller and heavier than Bulbasaur, its trademark bulb becomes a pink flower-bud, and four leaves now appear at the base of this bud. The Pokemon\'s legs are more stout, allowing it to hold up the bigger bulb, yet limiting its previous ability to stand on its hind legs. [2] Its eyes now look more aggressive and intimidating. As before, Ivysaur and its bulb share a mutualistic relationship; bathing in sunlight allows both to continue growing. [3] Eventually, the bud will give off a sweet scent, a signal that it will bloom soon, and that its host will evolve. An Ivysaur will spend more time bathing in sunlight in order to reach evolution. [4]",
        "Venusaur, known in Japan as Fushigibana , is a Grass/Poison type Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. Created by Ken Sugimori, Venusaur first appeared in the video games Pokemon Red and Blue and subsequent sequels, later appearing in various merchandise, spinoff titles and animated and printed adaptations of the franchise.",
        "Charmander, known as Hitokage  in Japan, is a Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. Created by Ken Sugimori, Charmander first appeared in the video games Pokemon Red, Blue and Green and subsequent sequels, later appearing in various merchandise, spinoff titles and animated and printed adaptations of the franchise. The end of a Charmander\'s tail is alight with a flame, and the flame\'s size reflects both the physical health and the emotions of the individual.",
        "Charmeleon , Rizdo, Lizard is the evolved form of Charmander, and the pre-evolved form of Charizard. Charmeleon, known as the Flame Pokemon, are bipedal lizard Pokemon with yellow bellies and soles, three clawed feet and hands, and a flame at the end of their tails. They are darker-skinned than Charmander, possess a bumpy horn on their heads, and take on a more intimidating appearance. Charmeleon are excessively savage and short-tempered by nature, [25] and they are powerful fighters due to their temperament. The flame on its tail may burn a bluish white when the Pokemon is excited, [26] and the air temperature often raises to very high levels when the tail flame is waved around. [27] It first appears in Pokemon Red and Blue.",
        "Charizard, known in Japan as Lizardon , Rizadon, is a Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. Created by Ken Sugimori, Charizard first appeared in the video games Pocket Monsters Red and Green and subsequent sequels. They have later appeared in various merchandise, spinoff titles and animated and printed adaptations of the franchise. Shin-ichiro Miki, the actor who voices James in the original Japanese version of the Pokemon anime, voices Charizard in both the Japanese and English-language versions of the anime. An orange, dragon-like Pokemon, Charizard is the evolved form of Charmeleon, which is the evolved form of Charmander. It has two other forms, which are its Mega Evolution: Mega Charizard X and Mega Charizard Y.",
        "Squirtle enigame , is a Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. It was originally conceived by Game Freak\'s character development team and finalized by Ken Sugimori. Its name was changed from Zenigame to Squirtle during the English localization of the series in order to give it a \"clever and descriptive name.\" In animated appearances, Squirtle is voiced in Japanese by Rikako Aikawa and in English localizations by Eric Stuart. Squirtle, in the anime, never evolved for reasons never truly explained by the creators.",
        "Wartortle , Kamru, Kamei, known as the Turtle Pokemon, is the evolved form of Squirtle. It has a slightly more intimidating appearance than its preceding form; aside from an increased height and weight, it now has darker skin, eyes with smaller pupils, and two protruding fangs. Its shell may receive scars from battles that these Pokemon seek out. [45] A Wartortle also gets a pair of feathery ears, and its tail becomes white, fluffy, and too long to completely hide within its shell; [46] these appendages greatly aid this Pokemon in swimming, acting as oars and/or fins. [47] The tail also happens to be a highly valued collectors\' item, which has caused people to hunt this Pokemon\, dwindling their numbers. The reason for such poaching may very well be that a Wartortle tail is a symbol of longevity in the Pokemon world, supposedly allowing the creature to live for thousands of years. [48]",
        "Blastoise, known in Japan as Kamex , Kamekkusu, is a Water type Pokemon species in Nintendo and Game Freak\'s Pokemon franchise. Created by Ken Sugimori, Blastoise first appeared in the video games Pokemon Red and Blue and subsequent sequels, later appearing in various merchandise, spinoff titles and animated and printed adaptations of the franchise. It is the final evolution of Squirtle, and next evolution of Wartortle. Its name is composed by the words \"Blast\" and \"Tortoise\".",
        "Caterpie , Kyatap, known as the \"worm\" Pokemon, [54] was designed by Ken Sugimori. [55] Satoshi Tajiri, creator of the series, took heavy inspiration from his childhood hobby of insect collection in creating the various Pokemon species. [56] Caterpie was based on the design of a caterpillar, specifically the caterpillar of the Swallowtail butterfly. [57] Caterpie\'s name is also derived from the word caterpillar. [58] Caterpie have green skin with a yellow underbelly, yellow spots, and large red osmeterium protruding from their foreheads. [59] Their green bodies are useful for camouflage in foliage, [60] their eyes are patterned to scare away predators, [61] their suction-cup feet allow them to climb any surface, [62] and the osmeterium on their heads can project a horrid stench to repel predators. [63] Caterpie is the smallest of all the original Pokemon, [64] and grows in size by shedding its skin. [54] Caterpie evolves into Metapod, and eventually Butterfree. [65] Prior to Pokemon Platinum, It could only ever learn two attacks, Tackle and String Shot, and is severely limited in ability until it evolves. [59]",
        "Metapod , Toranseru, Toranse, known as the Cocoon Pokemon, are pupal Pokemon found in the wild early in the Kanto and Johto regions, of which its larval form is the caterpillar-like Caterpie. They can evolve into the butterfly-like Butterfree. While Metapod is classified as a cocoon Pokemon, it bears more resemblance to a chrysalis. A Metapod\'s exterior is regularly hardened to protect its soft and tender innards while undergoing metamorphosis to eventually become a Butterfree. [74] To conserve energy for this event, the Metapod barely moves. [75] While this shell is said to be as hard as steel, a large sudden impact could cause its vulnerable body to pop out, leaving it completely exposed. [76]",
        "Butterfree , Batafur, known as the Butterfly Pokemon, are fully developed, butterfly-like Pokemon that have hatched from their pupal Metapod forms. Butterfree resembles a vaguely anthropomorphic butterfly. Unlike true insects, it only has four legs, which are a pale blue color. It has a nose-like structure which is a similar color. It has large veined wings which are white with black markings. These markings can help distinguish male and female individuals. It has large compound eyes which tend to be a reddish color. Butterfree feed on honey from flowers, and they rub the honey onto the hairs on their legs to transport the honey back to their nests.  Like members of the order Lepidoptera, Butterfrees wings are covered in fine scales that are water\-repellant and allow it to fly in heavy rains, [78] something many other insect Pokemon such as Masquerain cannot do, and are also coated in toxic dust that can be directed at an opponent in battle through wing-flapping. [79] Butterfree can be seen multiple times in the anime one episode you can find it in is Bye Bye Butterfree.",
        "Weedle , Bdoru, Beedl, known as the Hairy Bug Pokemon, are larval Pokemon found in the wild early in the Kanto and Johto regions. They are very weak Pokemon that are captured to be evolved into their cocoon-like Kakuna form and eventually into the hornet-like Beedrill form. Weedle have little pink feet and a pink, round nose. Commonly spotted in the forests and grasslands, eating leaves, Weedle are well-protected from predators by sharp two-inch barbs on their heads [80] which secrete a strong poison, and another stinger is on each Weedle's rear. Sniffing with its big red proboscis, a Weedle uses its extremely acute sense of smell to find the types of leaves it eats. ften living in forests and grasslands  it eats its weight in leaves every day. [83]",
        "Kakuna , Kokn, Cocoo, known as the Cocoon Pokemon, are pupal Pokemon found in the Kanto and Johto regions, of which its larval form is the worm-like Weedle. They can evolve into the hornet-like Beedrill. Kakuna is a yellow, cone-shaped cocoon Pokemon. Kakuna has a dome-shaped head and black, triangular eyes. Within the shell, a Kakuna busily prepares itself for evolution into its adult form, and the amount of energy released by this process makes the shell hot to the touch. [88] Kakuna can use a poisonous sting to defend themselves if disturbed. [89]",
        "Beedrill , Supi, Spea, known as the Poison Bee Pokemon, are fully developed, wasp-like Pokemon that have hatched from their pupal Kakuna forms. Although they are hornet-like, they only have four legs, the front two tipped with long stingers. It has veined wings, and another stinger on its abdomen that contains its most potent venom. [90] Beedrill are extremely territorial, and will be set off by anything that approaches a Beedrill nest. [91] When angered, Beedrill attack in a furious swarm. [92]",
        "Pidgey , Popp, known as the Tiny Bird Pokemon, resembles a small, plump-bodied bird. It is a brown color, with a lighter colored throat and belly. The tips of its wings share this cream color. Both its feet and beak are a pinkish-gray color. Its plumage is fairly nondescript, particularly compared to its evolutions Pidgeotto and Pidgeot. It has black markings around its eyes and a small crest of brown and cream feathers above its eyes. Pidgey are docile and prefer to avoid conflict. If disturbed, however, it can ferociously strike back [95] and will use its wings to stir up clouds of sand in an attempt to distract its would-be opponent and escape. [19] Pidgey also uses this technique to bring its preferred prey of small insects into the open. [96] Pidgey seems to possess magnetoception, as it is capable of returning to its nest from any location without fail. [97]",
        "Pidgeotto , Pijon, Pigeo, known as the Bird Pokemon, is a larger and stronger form that Pidgey takes when it gains enough experience. It is a large raptor-like bird. While its primary color is brown, its plumage is much more elaborate than its pre-evolution, Pidgey. Its head-crest is much longer than Pidgey's and is a reddish color. The plumage of its tail is also quite colorful, alternating between red and yellow. Other than its ornamental plumage, its basic coloration is similar to Pidgey, with pinkish-gray feet and black markings around its eyes. Pidgeotto is extremely territorial, generally claiming a large area with its nest built in the center. Full of vitality, it constantly patrols its territory, mercilessly attacking intruders. They fly about in circular patterns while hunting, and can spot the movements of their prey on the ground no matter how high they fly. [100] Pidgeotto attacks with its wickedly sharp talons and carries its prey, including Exeggcute and Magikarp, back to its nest from as far as 60 miles away or more. [101] Pidgeotto appeared in the Pokemon anime as one of series star Ash Ketchum's first Pokemon. It eventually evolved into Pidgeot.",
        "Pidgeot , Pijotto, Pigeo, known as the Bird Pokemon, is the fully grown and developed form of the Pidgey species evolution line. Pidgeot is noticeably larger than its pre-evolution. Its plumage tends to be larger and glossier. The feathers on its head-crest are nearly as long as its body, and are yellow and red. Its tail feathers are red colored. Like its previous evolutions, its underbelly is a tan color, and it has black markings around its eyes. With their powerful chest muscles at work, Pidgeot can flap their wings fast enough to whip up gusts of winds to rival tornadoes. [102] Pidgeot are very aerodynamic, capable of soaring to an altitude of 3300 feet [103] and reaching speeds of up to Mach 2. [104] Like Pidgeotto, Pidgeot feed on Magikarp by swooping from the sky and snatching them out of the water with their talons. [103] Pidgeot appear very similar to Pidgeotto, so much so that one has been easily mistaken for the other, even by official sources. [105] Ash's Pidgeotto evolves into Pidgeot in the anime, and leaves his Pidgeot to protect its a group of Pidgey and Pidgeotto.",
        "Rattata , Koratt is known as the Mouse Pokemon. Rattata resemble small purple rats with large red eyes, cream bellies, paw soles and square fangs. Rattata has a long, slightly, purple curled tail. Rattata has large incisors and a long whisker on both sides that may be worn down by gnawing. Rattata have three-toed paws, which are the same color as its underbelly. They walk on four legs. Rattata has a large teeth, which grow constantly to gnaw on hard things to wear them down. Rattata are among the earliest Pokemon that can be caught by players, so much so that it is said that the presence of one Rattata indicates the presence of more than forty Rattata in the area. [106] They make their nests almost anywhere [107] and as extreme omnivores eat anything they can scavenge. [108] A Rattata\'s fangs grow continuously throughout its lifespan, so it whittles them down to a comfortable size by gnawing on hard objects. [109] They are best known for their Quick Attack, which allows them to strike their enemy first, even if it is not their turn to do so.",
        "Raticate , Ratt, known as the Mouse Pokemon, is a larger and stronger form that Rattata takes when it gains enough experience. Raticate resemble large tawny rats with small black eyes, a yellow belly, a large cream-colored tail and the ability to stand on its hind legs. Raticate is mostly tawny in color with a cream-colored underside. In the main Pokemon game series, a Raticate is only acquired when a Rattata grows past experience level 20 and is evolved into a Raticate. Compared to a Rattata, a Raticate is far more of a predator, and the majority of its features are adapted for this purpose. Its whiskers give it balance and it slows down if they are cut off. [115] A female always has shorter whiskers. Its webbed feet allow it to swim as it hunts prey, [116] and its fangs are tough enough to topple concrete buildings by gnawing on them. [117]",
        "Spearow , Onisuzum are known as the Tiny Bird Pokemon. Their English names come from the words \"spear\" and \"sparrow.\" When they are trained greatly, they can evolve into Fearow. Spearow are very small birds with rough plumage. They have the beak shape similar to that of raptors. Their pink feet each have three talons. They are noted for being frail, for which they make up for with their \"Mirror Move\" ability. [121] They eat insects in grassy areas by flushing them out with their stubby wings, and plucking at them with their beaks. [122] A Spearow's wings aren't good for long distance travel or high flying, [123] but one is able to fly at high speeds by flapping its wings very rapidly. [124] Spearow are very territorial, constantly buzzing about and calling with a loud cry that can be heard from half a mile away. This cry serves to scare away predators and to keep in touch with other Spearow, though the latter is reserved as an alarm to its kind. [125]",
        "Fearow , Onidoriru, Onidril, known as the Beak Pokemon, is a bird Pokemon that evolves from Spearow at level 20. Fearow is a large brown bird with a vulture-like neck. It has a large, long pointed beak and a red crown-like line of spikes upon its head. It also bears huge wings. All characteristics being a radical departure from its short-winged, stubby-beaked pre-evolved form Spearow. Fearow uses its great wings to catch air currents [128] and effortlessly glide over large distances for as long as a day without having to land or rest. [129] It flies high into the sky, and swoops down at its prey. [130] By using a combination of its neck and beak, it has a large reach, allowing it to pluck bugs from the ground or easily pluck prey from soil or water as it swoops down. [131] If it senses danger, it avoids it if possible.",
        "Ekans , bo, Arb is known as the Rattlesnake Pokemon. This reptilian Pokemon has a rattle at the tip of its tail, and is mostly purple while its underbelly, eyes, rattle, and the \"bands\" on it are yellow. They swallow whole the eggs of small bird Pokemon, such as Pidgey or Spearow. [133] Ekans are able to detach their jaws to swallow large prey whole, although this makes their bodies heavy. [134] Its highly poisonous fangs make it a hazard in the wild as they slither through the grass and unexpectedly strike. [135] Ekans also shares other characteristics as snakes, such as using its tongue to test the air for the presence of prey, [136] and shedding its skin.",
        "Arbok , bokk, known as the Cobra Pokemon, are a larger and stronger form that Ekans take when they gain enough experience. In the main Pokemon game series, an Arbok is only acquired when an Ekans evolves. Arbok is a reptilian with purple scales over most of its body. It has lost the rattle it had on its tail as an Ekans. Like a cobra, it can spread out its ribs into a hood. On its \"hood\", it has a design much like an angry face. The frightening patterns on its hood have been studied and six variations have been confirmed. [139] Each design is native to a certain region. [140] It has a nasty bite with deadly venom. Terrifically strong, it is capable of crushing opponents by coiling its body around them and constricting. It can even flatten steel oil drums. [141] Rather vicious, Arbok are territorial. If it encounters an enemy, it raises its head, intimidating the opponent with the frightening pattern on its body, then they lash out at intruders with long fangs tipped with deadly venom. [142] With a vengeful nature, it won\'t give up a chase after prey or an opponent, no matter how far, once it targets it prey. [143]",
        "Pikachu Japanese:  are a species of Pokemon, fictional creatures that appear in an assortment of comic books, animated movies and television shows, video games, and trading card games licensed by The Pokemon Company, a Japanese corporation. The Pikachu design was conceived by Ken Sugimori. Pikachu first appeared in Pokemon Red and Green in Japan, and later in the first internationally-released Pokemon video games Pokemon Red and Blue for the original Game Boy."]

#----------------------------------------------------------------
#  Main
#----------------------------------------------------------------

numbers=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25']

empty_line_2= ' '*80


print('Pick a Pokemon!')
print(empty_line_2)
print('The Pokemon are: (1)Bulbasaur, (2)Ivysaur, (3)Venusaur, (4)Charmander, (5)Charmeleon, (6)Charizard, (7)Squirtle, (8)Wartortle, (9)Blastoise, (10)Caterpie, (11)Metapod, (12)Butterfree, (13)Weedle,  (14)Kakuna, (15)Beedrill, (16)Pidgey, (17)Pidgeotto, (18)Pidgeot, (19)Rattata, (20)Raticate, (21)Spearow, (22)Fearow, (23)Ekans, (24)Arbok, (25)Pikachu')

pick=raw_input('Enter a number between 1 and 25 or esc to exit: ')

while pick != chr(27):
    if pick in numbers:
        print_box(int(pick)-1)
    else:
        print('Wrong Input!')
    print(empty_line_2)
    print('Pick a Pokemon!')
    print(empty_line_2)
    print('The Pokemon are: (1)Bulbasaur, (2)Ivysaur, (3)Venusaur, (4)Charmander, (5)Charmeleon, (6)Charizard, (7)Squirtle, (8)Wartortle, (9)Blastoise, (10)Caterpie, (11)Metapod, (12)Butterfree, (13)Weedle,  (14)Kakuna, (15)Beedrill, (16)Pidgey, (17)Pidgeotto, (18)Pidgeot, (19)Rattata, (20)Raticate, (21)Spearow, (22)Fearow, (23)Ekans, (24)Arbok, (25)Pikachu')
    pick=raw_input('Enter a number between 1 and 25 or esc to exit: ')
sys.exit('This program is finished. Goodbye!')
```

I was making a pokemon pokedex. Then I came across this. It works properly if I do it on repl.it. My main question is why isn't the chr(27) working as it should be functioning? Any help to get it working is accepted. Why it works there and not here, I don't know.

Comment: Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: chr(27) is *probably* working, what might not be working is that the raw_input might not pick it up.  Print the output from raw_input and see what happens when you press escape.

Comment: It does nothing at all. I do it and then hit enter just to see and then it says 'Wrong Input!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use ESC, try looking at this similar question:
[Making python quit program instantly when hitting ESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554755/making-python-quit-program-instantly-when-hitting-esc)

Easiest solution. Don't use ESC at all. You are having the user input a number. Use a character such as Q or any non-number input to terminate the command.

Comment: Wouldn't it work a bit better since the numbers are string rather than integers because of raw_input?

Comment: @jweaver True raw_input() means the user input will always be a string. Using a string (single character) is less fuss with dealing with special inputs such as space, tab, esc, etc. If there isn't a requirement to use esc, I wouldn't bother with it.